# .war file not working on Eclipse w/ WebLogic 10.3.6 after working on 12.1.3 - can't figure out based on error log

Tags: java, jquery, eclipse, oracle, weblogic

So I downloaded weblogic 12.1.3 from oracle which came with a different version of Eclipse (Kepler). When I took my current .war file and imported it, I could run it through a local server, and it worked fine.  Now I need to get it to work on weblogic 10.3.6 - I ended up deleting the Eclipse that came with 12.1.3 and downloaded the one that came with 10.3.6 (Indigo).  Now it is not starting on the server, and I can't figure out the error messages.

This pops up when I try running it on the server:

```
Error(s) found in module 'FileTrackerWAR2'. Publish was cancelled. See "Problems" view for details.
Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Arguments at jquery-1.6.2.min.js
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ObjectLiteral at jquery-1.6.2.min.js
Syntax error on token "Invalid Regular Expression Options", no accurate correction available at jquery-1.6.2.min.js
```

The Error Log also shows:

`Failed to publish module
        module named '_auto_generated_ear_' failed to deploy. 
               weblogic.application.ModuleException: Failed to load webapp:'FileTrackerWAR'`

When I tried deleting jquery-1.6.2.min.js (because I don't think I actually use it - I link to this via https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js) I get this in the error log:

```
Failed to publish module
   org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Module named '_auto_generated_ear_' failed to deploy. See Error Log view for more detail.
   Contains: weblogic.application.ModuleException: Failed to load webapp: 'FileTrackerWAR'
   java.lang.Exception: Exception received from deployment driver. See Error Log view for more detail.
   Caused by: weblogic.application.ModuleException: Failed to load webapp: 'FileTrackerWAR'
   Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/gm/gif/FileTrackerResultsServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

Really confused right now. Would appreciate some help.

ANSWERED/FIGURED IT OUT: Like jikku told me, I was running the wrong version of java.  It took me a while to get it working after figuring that out because I had to change the Dynamic Web Module (by going to the settings file) and then some project facet stuff. Tbh I don't know if I could recreate it. It came to be pretty frustrating because I was just making educated guesses towards the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

Check 'Prolems tab'  make sure no more errors are there. If any please resolve that and then try.

Comment: I did. There are no errors in the problems tab when I delete 1.6.2.min.js, and I just added what's in the error log after I try running it on the server in my original question (in the last text box)

Comment: By llooking into this "Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError" it seems the java version used to compile is different from that in server which you are trying to run. Also pls check - In eclipse project=>Proerties=>java compiler; set "the compiler compliance level" to the version according to your jre or jdk.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to deploy to Weblogic 12.1.3 and the solution was indent the Java Script `moment.min.js` version 2.8.4, and remove a exrta brace on the `switch` sentence over the `as` attibute:

```
    as : function (a) {
        var b,
        c;
        if (a = x(a), "month" === a || "year" === a)
            return b = this._days + this._milliseconds / 864e5, c = this._months + 12 * pb(b), "month" === a ? c : c / 12;
        switch (b = this._days + Math.round(qb(this._months / 12)), a) {
        case "week":
            return b / 7 + this._milliseconds / 6048e5;
        case "day":
            return b + this._milliseconds / 864e5;
        case "hour":
            return 24 * b + this._milliseconds / 36e5;
        case "minute":
            return 24 * b * 60 + this._milliseconds / 6e4;
        case "second":
            return 24 * b * 60 * 60 + this._milliseconds / 1e3;
        case "millisecond":
            return Math.floor(24 * b * 60 * 60 * 1e3) + this._milliseconds;
        default:
            throw new Error("Unknown unit " + a)
        }
    },
```